# Do I need separate views for creating new data and loading existing data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form that displays appointment information that is populated by angular. Everything works great when I'm loading an existing appointment into the form but I get a bunch of null reference errors when I try to create a new appointment and there's no existing data for angular to populate the fields with.

For example, here's a snippet from one of my views:

```
<fieldset class="form-inline extra-padding-right">
    <legend class="sr-only">Event Information</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>ID:</label>
        <p class="form-control-static">{{ eventId }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Title:</label>
        <p class="form-control-static">{{ eventTitle }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Event Status:</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="ddlEventStatus" ng-model="eventStatus"
                ng-options="es as es.EventStatusName for es in eventStatusList track by es.EventStatusId">
        </select>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

`eventId`, `eventTitle` and `eventStatus` are attached to `$scope` in the controller and are all null because this will be a new appointment.

Do I have to create separate html views for creating a new appointment and loading an existing one or is there some way to put conditionals in my view so it only tries to populate fields when it's loading an existing appointment?

Answer (score 0):

Can often use same controller and view for edit/create and simply toggle a flag variable in scope:

Something like:

```
$scope.editMode = 'create';
$scope.startEdit = function(event){
   $scope.editMode = 'edit';
   $scope.event = event;
}
$scope.saveEdit = function(){

   $http.post(url,$scope.event).then(function(resp) {
       $scope.editMode = 'create';
       $scope.event = {}; // reset event object
   });
}
```

Since you should always always use an object in `ng-model` your view should use output more like:

```
<span>{{ editMode == 'create' ? "New Event" : "Edit Event"}}</span>
{{ event.id }}
<input ng-model="event.id">
```